# R says that the column doesn't exist but when I check it it seems to be alright

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I'm doing a 2-way repeated measurements ANOVA in R with libraries:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
```

I have two groups: `months` and `distance` and the dependent variable is `CO2`:

> distance  month     CO2
>
> 0 metres   july     234

I've checked normality and made the summarise and everything seems to work fine, but when I try to make the ANOVA:

```r
CO2.aov <- anova_test(
  data = field_data, dv = CO2, wid = id,
  within = c(month, distance)
)
```

It says that the column `CO2` doesn't exist.

However, when I check if it can read it (`field_data$CO2`), I get this:

```r
  [1]  163.05951  246.20906  309.92105  182.49706  251.60838  139.30249  617.68237
  [8]  263.48688  332.59820  222.45204  262.40702  156.58032  263.48688  461.10205
 [15]  956.75975  539.93214  673.83531  920.04437  846.61360  826.09617  792.62038
 [22]  463.26178  948.12084  248.36878  208.41381  265.64661  199.77489  188.97625
 [29]  203.01448  495.65770  187.89638  583.12671  776.42242  619.84210 1017.23215
 [36]  364.99413  359.59481  650.07830  699.75205  726.74866  526.97377  213.33134
 [43]  222.50688  373.90331  245.44573  208.74357  177.77611  439.27904  141.07395
 [50]  244.29879  205.30274  303.93981  175.48223  258.06210   43.58382  610.17350
 [57]  781.06796  506.94866  416.34019  193.83331  336.05420  253.47433  286.73567
 [64]  451.89541  274.11930  219.06605  182.36389  232.82936  252.32739  211.03745
 [71]  293.61732  237.41713  380.78497  250.17889  485.15675  470.24650  448.45459
 [78]  347.52363  395.69522  591.82242  373.90331  482.86287  237.78076  231.52338
 [85]  238.82366  248.20975  299.31175  164.77790  613.22408  336.85608  345.19927
 [92]  278.45379  306.61204  503.71978  397.34417  548.56439  799.90283  435.93140
 [99]  727.94287  512.06296  494.33369  683.09825  456.78936 1088.78561  846.83325
[106]  466.17545  579.85134  336.85608  458.87516  408.81605  326.42710  351.45666
[113]  544.39280  635.12494  669.54057  733.15736  887.50627  739.41475  595.49481
[120]  593.40901  599.66640  565.25076  900.02105
```

In addition, I get warning messages:

> Warning messages:
>   1: NA detected in rows: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123.
>   Removing this rows before the analysis. 
>   2: Factor `month` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
>   3: Factor `distance` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
>   4: Factor `month` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
>   5: Factor `distance` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`

After the initial suggestions and getting the same error again R said:

> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I tried that and got:

> Internal error: Trace data is not square.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

`structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87), nest = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), distance = c("1 m", "0.75 m", "0.5 m", "0.25 m", "0 m", "1 m", "0.75 m", "0.5 m", "0.25 m", "0 m", "1 m", "0.75 m", "0.5 m", "0.25 m", "0 m"), month = c("may", "may", "may", "may", "may", "july", "july", "july", "july", "july", "september", "september", "september", "september", "september"), CO2 = c(163.059506384766, 246.209055998189, 309.921048559124, 182.497063437254, 251.608377401658, 213.331337579618, 222.506878980892, 373.903312101911, 245.445732484076, 208.743566878981, 237.78076433121, 231.523375796178, 238.823662420382, 248.20974522293, 299.311751592357)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: did you try using quotes?

Comment: Yes, I tried and I get the same message

Comment: I tried your code with the data provided and I don't get the error mentioned. Instead, I got this error: `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases`.